# Can this be done with CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I have css classes that will automatic get names from a jquery script:
so it will be like `#imgHere01`, `#imgHere22`, `#imgHereSomething`, `#imgHereAnother`, etc.
Can I force CSS to control all of them?
Like

```
#imgHere_ALL {width:333px;}
```

or `#imgHere_xxx` so it will affect everyclass will be generated after `imgHere`.

I dont know if it is possible with CSS.
Maybe jQuery?

Comment: Please format your code http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Can you give them all a second class or attribute with the exact same name?

Comment: No, this cannot be done with pure CSS

Comment: I've done something similar to create a table of contents. I've included adding a class '.button' to identify them as a collection, no matter where they are in the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use CSS regular expression selector:**

```
div[id^='imgHere']{
   /** styles */
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mhAZw/)

This will select all `div`s that have an ID beginning with "imgHere". But as suggested, a better practice is to give all the elements a common class name.

Answer (score 2):

A much better approach would be to give them all a shared class.  Then you could do something like this:

```
.imgHere{
   width: 333px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if they share some common element (such as a class, parent, etc.), then you should be able to use [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) to style them the same way.

ie:

```
.myImages {
    //Whatever styling you want applied to all
}
```

or

```
parent img {
   //Whatever styling you want applied to all
}
```

You can also do this with jQuery, but it is simpler to do with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a Css class for this:

```
.image-all
{
    width: 333px;
}
```

then just make sure to add it; however you create your images:

```
$('<img />').addClass('image-all');
```

---

Or let's say that you cannot add a class, because it's a third party script. Then maybe you can have them in a container:

```
<div class="image-all">
    ... image container
</div>
```

then in your CSS:

```
.image-all img
{
    width: 333px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding you correctly, but this should be pretty simple in CSS. If you want something to affect "all things" then just give it another class in CSS. This is good for static things such as height, and width.

Give them one single class to share.

Answer (score 0):

You could use attribute selector:

```
img[id="imgHere"] {
    /* css */
}
```

This selector relies on a modern browser,though, so IE less than 9 is unlikely to play well. It would be easier simply to add a class with the jQuery script that generates the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these [css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/)

```
#imgHere ~ something
#imgHere + something
div[id^='imgHere'] ~ something
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS selector `*[class^=imgHere] { width:333px}` .  replace the `*` with a more specific CSS selector to make it more efficient.  CSS selector information can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).